# How update listView in android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I need to change just first row in my ListView. I used such way:

```
private void updateAdapter(int number) {
    String value = Integer.toString(number);
    list_.clear();
    list_.add(value);
    adapter_.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But, does anybody know another way, like myAdapter.update(newValue)? I use simple adapter

```
   private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_;
```

and ListView

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:paddingBottom="150dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your add or remove elements from your data source (which I assume is `list_` here) and you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the ListView will get recalculated in the designated way **based on** your (changed) data source.

Therefore it wouldn't make sense to directly update your adapter (with the proposed function `adapter.update()`).

If you're worried about performance (which I think is your motivation here when only changing the first row) check [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) to see how the population of a ListView works.

Answer (score 0):

Get the element by using `getItem (int position)` from the SimpleAdapter class. No you can change the object inside the adapter.

After change value call...

```
 listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

... to refresh your UI.

See doc: [SimpleAdapter - getItem(int pos)](http://file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/Android/Android-sdk/docs/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29)